# Laravel: How to get the old selected value from the post request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravelcollective, laravel-form

I have laravel blade form with choose option:

```
{!! Form::select('id', [''=>'Choose:'] + $name, null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
```

but I need this Choose option only first time in that page, after submission I need to stay last value that I used.

I tried like this with old function:

```
{!! Form::select(
    'id', 
    ['' => 'Choose:'] + $name, 
    old('id', null), 
    ['class' => 'form-control]
) !!}
```

but this doesn't work. Also, I google old function with @if statement like this:

```
@if( old('id') == $name) selected="selected" @endif
```

but also after submit goes back to Choose...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Laravel Collective form then

```
{!! Form::select('id', [''=>'Choose:'] + $name, null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
```

should be enough.

Make sure you open form also using

```
{!! Form::open(...
```

and that you are using standard validation (otherwise make sure you redirect back using

```
->withInput()
```

Comment: ->withInput() after redirect is what missing. That's it, thanks @Marcin Nabiałek ;)

Comment: Of course, I had to wait 7 minutes so I could mark ;)